# What does applying as.numeric to a dendrogram in R do?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

When I cut a dendrogram tree:

```
## 4. 3-cluster solution
cl.hw3 <- cutree(cl.ward, k=3)
```

And then try to run a logistic regression on it:

```
## 7. Logistic regression
cl1 <- as.numeric(cl.hw3==2)
logreg1 <- glm(cl1 ~ sex + birthyr + plingu02, family=binomial, data=biofam)
summary(logreg1)
```

What is it that happens in the first step (cl1 <- as.numeric(cl.hw3==1)? Does the assignment operator == recut the dendrogram tree clusters with the number I give (2 rather than 3 in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `cl.hw3==2` returns a logical with values `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

The `as.numeric(cl.hw3==2)` transforms the logical into a numeric variable by replacing the `TRUE`'s with 1's and the `FALSE`'s with 0's.

Setting `as.numeric(cl.hw3==3)` does not cut the tree differently. It simply defines the resulting indicator variable for belonging to the third group rather than to the second one.
The logistic regression would then be for the probability to belong to the third cluster.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1.  Using `head(cl.hw3==2)` and `head(as.numeric(cl.hw3==2))` would show the initial values